# How to delete a resource with amplify cli for only one environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

Imagine i have configured one environment with the aws amplify cli (production). In the production environment i have configured a hosting resource with S3/CDN and a auth resource. Now i want to create a dev environment that only contains a auth resource.

Do i have the ability to configure those environments independent from each other? If i create a new environment via `amplify add env` and after that publish the stack i get the summary based on the previous created production environment:

```
| Category | Resource name           | Operation | Provider plugin   |
| -------- | ----------------------- | --------- | ----------------- |
| Hosting  | S3AndCloudFront         | Create    | awscloudformation |
| Auth     | auth2d58178c            | Create    | awscloudformation |
```

What happens if i now delete the hosting resource. Will this affect my production environment as well?

I would like to split dev and production environments to use no hosting for the dev environment. This should be used more or less for developers to use services like cognito during their local development. But i want a production (and later a staging) environment with a configured hosting resource.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

yes, it is.

[amplify/backend folder](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/usage#amplifybackend-folder) "contains the latest local development of the backend resources specifications to be pushed to the cloud". There you can find a `backend-config.json` with the resources that will be pushed to the cloud so no one forbids you to only have the `hosting` category defined in the master branch/production environment.

If you do that:

1. be careful on merging dev environment in master to be sure that you aren't removing `hosting` category;
2. you can run `amplify env checkout <current-env-name>` "[to populate the CLI runtime files and make it aware of the resources changes](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/quickstart#custom-cloudformation-stacks)"

With that being said, are you aware of the [recommended approach of "Team-members working on their own sandbox environments"](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/quickstart#team-members-working-on-their-own-sandbox-environments-recommended) or [sharing the same dev backend](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/quickstart#team-members-sharing-the-same-dev-backend) by [using S3 static web hosting for DEV and S3+CloudFront for PROD](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/quickstart#stages)? Take a different path from a standard procedure tend to lead in pain somewhere in future.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately most of the suggested alternative method depend on the CloudFormation resource for Amplify to still be in place as well as the `backend-config.json` file.

However if you ran into an issue where you for example you accidentally did for example a `git reset --hard`, and you find yourself in a situation where locally in your `backend-config.json` the environment you wish you delete no longer exists but it still persits in the [Amplify web console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/amplify/home?region=us-east-1#/):

[image: AWS Amplify console]

In this case where you are unable to directly use the Amplify CLI to remove the faulty environment, you can choose to directly use the AWS CLI instead of Amplify's CLI.

Initially you need to retrieve your AWS APP ID's

```
$ aws amplify list-apps --region us-east-1 | grep appId

            "appId": "abc123def456gh",
```

With the `appId` retrieved you can list the branches registered on AWS for this Amplify app:

```
## PUT YOUR APP ID: 
$ aws amplify list-branches --region us-east-1 --app-id abc123def456gh | grep branchName

           "branchName": "master",
```

To remove the Amplify resources for a specific branch you can only remove the Amplify app through CLI:

```
## ENTER YOUR APP ID AND AMPLIFY BRANCH NAME
$ aws amplify delete-backend-environment --region us-east-1 --app-id abc123def456gh --environment-name master

$ aws amplify delete-branch --region us-east-1 --app-id abc123def456gh  --branch-name master
```

There you go, the Amplify environment no longer exists in Amplify console. You can now go ahead and check in [Cloudformation console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=us-east-1#/stacks?filteringText=&filteringStatus=active&viewNested=true&hideStacks=false) if there any stacks deployed by Amplify for this environment which still exists (Search for `amplify-<YOURAPPNAME>-<ENVIRONMENT>-173612` (e.g. the Cloudformation stack name can be `amplify-reactpoc-master-123456`). And if you like you can use `$ amplify init` to create a fresh new Amplify environment under the same name.